# PocketSphinx for Android conflicts with google speech recognition

Tags: android, text-to-speech, speech-to-text, cmusphinx, keyword-spotting

I have implemented the pocketsphinx keyword spotting tool in my app and have it running in a sticky service.  Keyword spot works great!  The problem is that i can no longer use anything related to google speech while it's running (navigation, camera, video, speech to text). Does anybody have any suggestions on how to make them play nicely together?

Or even some kind of receiver for anything related to google speech so that I know to cancel sphinx?

Comment: Please, elaborate on the problem, give more details.

Comment: When sphinx is running in background and I open the video recorder it says Mic is in use and closes. Same goes for keyboard text to speech.

Comment: Ok, give us some time to research the problem. Next time, though, file the issue directly to [CMUSphinx bug tracker](http://sourceforge.net/p/cmusphinx/bugs/).

Answer (score 1):

Android to date doesn't provide any way to arbitrate microphone access.

See for details https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61643

You can stop the recognizer in onStop when activity stops.